# Launch VLC from Terminal and set default renderer to ChromeCast from start (NO GUI)

Tags: vlc, chromecast

I am on Mac, and tried basically:

```
 vlc --sout '#R5 TV (Chromecast)' --sout-chromecast-ip=192.168.0.8 --demux-filter=demux_chromecast
```

Vlc opens, but it does not seem to select the renderer to the chrome cast in my menu.

[image]

How can I make this choice automatic? I believe most things are possible from Terminal for VLC.

I looked at

```
vlc --longhelp --advanced
```

Which is quite long but could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
path/to/vlc '/nothing.mp4' --sout '#chromecast' --sout-chromecast-ip=192.168.0.8 --demux-filter=demux_chromecast"
```

seems to work on MacOS at least. It won't play nothing.mp4 but allows you to start playing anything, like with a VLC remote application from phone.